# Extract string from many brackets

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, cut

I have a file with this content:

```
    ok: [10.9.22.122] => {
        "out.stdout_lines": [
            "cgit-1.1-11.el7.x86_64",
            "python-paramiko-2.1.1-0.9.el7.noarch",
            "varnish-libs-4.0.5-1.el7.x86_64",
            "kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64"
        ]
    }
    ok: [10.9.33.123] => {
        "out.stdout_lines": [
            "python-paramiko-2.1.1-0.9.el7.noarch"
        ]
    }

    ok: [10.9.44.124] => {
        "out.stdout_lines": [
            "python-paramiko-2.1.1-0.9.el7.noarch",
            "kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64"
        ]
    }

   ok: [10.9.33.29] => {
       "out.stdout_lines": []
   }
   ok: [10.9.22.28] => {
       "out.stdout_lines": [
        "NetworkManager-tui-1:1.12.0-8.el7_6.x86_64", 
        "java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc-zip-debug-1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.noarch", 
        "java-1.8.0-openjdk-src-1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64", 
        "kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64", 
        "kernel-tools-3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64", 
    ]
}

ok: [10.2.2.2] => {
    "out.stdout_lines": [
        "monitorix-3.10.1-1.el6.noarch", 
        "singularity-runtime-2.6.1-1.1.el6.x86_64"
    ]
}

ok: [10.9.22.33] => {
    "out.stdout_lines": [
        "NetworkManager-1:1.12.0-8.el7_6.x86_64",
        "gnupg2-2.0.22-5.el7_5.x86_64", 
        "kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64", 
    ]
}
```

I need to extract the IP between `[]` if into `stout_line` contains `kernel*`.

I want to "emulate" substring, to save a 'block' of content into varible and go through the all file.
How would I use `sed`, or other, to do this if I have many delimiter?

Comment: The output would be: "The IP 10.9.44.124 cointain Kernel"

Comment: `10.9.22.122` should not printed?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I need to save all IP to containt Kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `GNU awk` solution:

```
awk -F'\\]|\\[' 'tolower($3)~/"out.stdout_lines" *:/ && tolower($4)~/"kernel/{print "The IP " $2 " cointain Kernel"}' RS='}' file
```

Output:

```
The IP 10.9.22.122 cointain Kernel
The IP 10.9.44.124 cointain Kernel
The IP 10.9.22.28 cointain Kernel
The IP 10.9.22.33 cointain Kernel
```

I used `]` or `[` as `FS` field separator, and `}` as `RS` record separator.
So the IP will just becomes `$2`.
This solution depends on the structure, that means `"out.stdout_lines"` needs to be in the field after `[ip]` like you showed in your example.

Another GNU awk way, no above limitation:

```
awk -F']' 'match(tolower($0),/"out\.stdout_lines": *\[([^\]]+)/,m){if(m[1]~/"kernel/)print "The IP " substr($1, index($1,"[")+1) " cointain Kernel"}' RS='}' file
```

Same output. The `tolower`s are for case insensitive match, If you want exact match, you can remove them or just use solutions from [Revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55050259/6).

Combine merits from above two ways, the **Third way**:

```
awk -F'\\]|\\[' 'match(tolower($0),/"out\.stdout_lines": *\[([^\]]+)/,m){if(m[1]~/"kernel/)print "The IP " $2 " cointain Kernel"}' RS='}' file
```

Change `tolower($0)` to `$0` if you don't need case insensitive match.

Comment: I tried the new solution and it works, i tried Revision 6 and i preferred that 'cause its fasterest... ¡¡thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ gawk -v RS="ok: " -F " => " '$2 ~ /[Kk]ernel/ { printf "The IP %s contains Kernel\n", $1 }' file
The IP [10.9.22.122] contains Kernel
The IP [10.9.44.124] contains Kernel
```

Answer (score 1):

since your data are pretty much well-formated, you can use awk(gawk):

```
awk '
    # get the ip address
    /ok:/ {ip = gensub(/[^0-9\.]/, "", "g", $2) }

    # check the stdout_lines block and print Kernal and ip saved from the above line
    /"out.stdout_lines":/,/\]/ { if (/\<[Kk]ernel\>/) print ip}
' file
#10.9.22.122
#10.9.44.124
#10.9.22.28
#10.9.22.28
#10.9.22.33
```

**Note**:

- I adjusted the regexes to reflect to your updated data.
- you might get more than one Kernel files for the same IP under the `out.stdout_lines` block, which will yield the same IP multiple times. If this happens just pipe the result to `| uniq`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/ok:/{s/[^0-9.]//g;:a;N;/]/!ba;/stdout_line.*kernel/P}' file
```

Set the `-n` to suppress implicit printing

If a line contains the the string `ok:` this is an IP address, strip the line of everything but integers and periods.

Append further lines until a line containing `]` is encountered and if the pattern space contains both `stdout_line` and `kernel`, print the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution:
    #!/bin/bash

```
AWK='
    /^ok:/ { gsub(/^.*\[/,""); gsub(/].*$/,""); ip=$0 }
    /"Kernel-default/ { if (ip) print ip; ip="" }
'
awk "$AWK" INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, this should work for most of the `awk`s I believe.(I have added `[kK]` in condition match so it should look for `kernal` OR `Kernal` both strings(since OP's previous sample was having capital `K` and now it has `k`small one, so thought to cover both here).

```
awk '
/ok/{
   gsub(/.*\[|\].*/,"")
   ip=$0
}
/stdout_line/{
   found=1
   next
}
found && /[kK]ernel/{
   print ip
}
/}/{
   ip=found=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program here.
/ok/{                       ##Checking condition if a line contains string ok in it then do following.
   gsub(/.*\[|\].*/,"")     ##Globally substituting everything till [ and everything till ] with NULL in current line.
   ip=$0                    ##Creating variable named ip whose values is current line value(edited one).
}                           ##Closing BLOCK for ok string check condition.
/stdout_line/{              ##Checking condition if a line contains stdout_line then do following.
   found=1                  ##Set value of variable named found to 1 here.
   next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                           ##Closing BLOCK for stdout_line string check condition here.
found && /[kK]ernel/{          ##Checking condition if variable found is NOT NULL and string Kernel found in current line then do following.
   print ip                 ##Printing value of variable ip here.
}                           ##Closing BLOCK for above condition now.
/}/{                        ##Checking condition if a line contains } then do following.
   ip=found=""              ##Nullify ip and found variable here.
}                           ##Closing BLOCK for } checking condition.
'   Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
10.9.22.122
10.9.44.124
10.9.22.28
10.9.22.28
10.9.22.33
```

Comment: This solution repeat multiple times the IP that contains "kernel".   Example: 35 times 10.9.22.123

Comment: For your given sample it worked. So is it like you have multiple same ips and you want to remove duplicates? Please confirm once? Trust me this should will one of the simplest solution provided here and compatible too if requirement is clear here, I can't see any other answer dealing with duplicate thing but if you can confirm I could enhance this then.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 's!\[(\S+)\].+?\{(.+?)\}!$y=$1;$x=$2;$x=~/kernel/ ? print "$y\n":""!sge'  brenn.log
10.9.22.122
10.9.44.124
10.9.22.28
10.9.22.33

$
```